# I can't add any ppa

Tags: ppa, repository

I don't know why but after a while I can't add any working ppa any more! When I try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
```

the output is:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I have ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: really I don't know . Sometimes Ago I install tor-browser and mabye it made the problem .

Comment: Can you do a `sudo apt-get update`? If yes, what are the contents of your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file?

Comment: yes I can . I don't have such file . I have auth.conf . Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Unable to add PPA repository from terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157730/44425)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

More info at http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html.